# Assembly - How can I perform arithmetic within these assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly

```
fsubr dword ptr [eax]
fst dword ptr [eax]
mov [ebp-00000084],00000000
```

What I'd like this to do is add instead of subtract, so that the difference it is getting will be greater than the original instead of lesser.

I know it's a very rookie question, I've literally only just started trying to learn about assembly, but the answer will help me understand a lot better.

Secondly, would it be possible to check if the stored operand was less than 0, and if it is, multiply it by -1 ? This would assure that is ALWAYS copies a greater operand to the memory and doesn't have lesser (in the event of something afflicting the value with a negative rather than a positive).

Comment: Thank you for the swift response, I have been reading into that link you sent alongside about half a dozen other sources to try and learn more about this.

It worked, changing to fadd, I didn't know what that f was, but I'm guessing it means float. The third line ay not be relevant, but it is indeed bunched with the other two in the task it is executing.. that's the final part where it copies over the old memory address. But apart from that, could you please detail what that line is doing exactly, like you did for the other two?

Edit: I'd +rep you for helping, but it says I need more rep.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in that fragment do the following:

```
fsubr dword ptr [eax]
```

This is a reverse subtract, subtracting the top of the floating point stack `st0` from the number found in memory at the address in the `eax` register, and puts the result back into `st0`.

```
fst dword ptr [eax]
```

That stores `st0` to the memory address pointed to by `eax`.

```
mov [ebp-00000084],00000000
```

This is not relevant to the computation.

- If you want to add rather than subtract, use the addition operation `fadd`.
- If you want to compare floating point numbers, use `fcom` or the special case `ftst0`.
- If you want to change the sign, use `fmul` to multiply with `-1`, or the special case `fchs`.

Documentation for the instructions is plentiful, for example the University of Illinois has an [x86 instruction reference](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref.html) document.